# Can't access a UIWebView apparently coming from storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, uiwebview, uipageviewcontroller

There's a view with one UIWebview in Portrait and two smaller UIWebViews in landscape - In landscape the two views represent the pages of a book and there's some pageview stuff going on. I can not determine where the second UIWebView is coming from. When the superview is loaded in landscape I can only access one of the the view on the left. The view on the right displays perfectly with the correct data, but I can't access it from the code until something causes the screen to redraw such as the page being "turned" or the orientation changing. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Also, my NSLog function isn't working anymore and I have no idea where to click to make it come back. Please help.

## Edit

Here's some code

```
// this is the function which is not accessing the view.
-(void) setCurrentTextSize:(int)cts {
     for(int pageViewIndex = 0; pageViewIndex < [arrayOfReaderViewControllers count]; pageViewIndex++) {
        readerViewController *r = [self arrayOfReaderViewControllers:pageViewIndex];
        [r setCurrentTextSize:cts];
        [r webViewDidFinishLoad:r.webView];
    }
}

//this function populates arrayOfReaderViewControllers
-(void)initializeArrayOfReaderViewControllers {
    readerViewController *vcLeft;
    if([self.delegate isFirstLoad]) {
        //we don't care what happens here 'cause it's not being called.
    } else {
        vcLeft = [readerViewController new];
        if ( lastPageNumber > currentPageNumber) {
            currentPageNumber        = lastPageNumber;
            [arrayOfReaderViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[self jumpToPageVC:vcLeft]];
            if(self.isLandscape) {
                vcLeft  = [arrayOfReaderViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
                [arrayOfReaderViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[self getNextPageViewController:vcLeft]];
            }
        }
    }
    [self.delegate doMoreInitialization];
}
```

Comment: Some code of yours would be immensely helpful.

Comment: I inherited this code so I'm not 100% on what's going on here and what's important, but I'll give it a shot.